# Lambda function output as object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are currently getting an AWS lambda response like this:

```
"{\"retailers\":[{\"address\":\"a\",\"retailerId\":1}, 
{\"address\":\"b\",\"retailerId\":2}]
,\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"type\":\"OK\",\"message\":\"Success\"}}"
```

The response is converting to json at the API Gateway using a code snippet:

```
$util.escapeJavaScript("$input.path('$')").replaceAll("\\","")
```

How we can directly make a json output from lambda function and serve as response body with out using the `escapeJavaScript` function?

```
    public class GetRetailerInfo implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) { 
        try{             
            JSONObject parameters=new JSONObject(input.toString());
            return APIUtil.getretailer(parameters,context).toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Unable to process the request. "+input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By providing POJOs as generic input and output parameters to you `RequestHandler` implementation, AWS Lambda will take care of the serialization and deserialization between JSON and Java for you. The example below is copied from the [Example 1: Creating Handler with Custom POJO Input/Output (Leverage the RequestHandler Interface)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html#java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces-pojo-handler-class) in the AWS Lambda developer guide:

```
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Request, Response> {

    public Response handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        String greetingString = String.format("Hello %s %s.", request.firstName, request.lastName);
        return new Response(greetingString);
    }
}
```

For example, if the event data in the Request object is:

```
{
  "firstName":"value1",
  "lastName" : "value2"
}
```

The method returns a Response object as follows:

```
{
  "greetings": "Hello value1 value2."
}
```

Please follow the link above to see full example including implementations of the `Request` and `Response` classes.